# Share an image on Facebook and redirect to Fan Page

Tags: html, facebook, email, redirect

I am trying to share an image on Facebook via Email Marketing but I am having trouble to redirect after the share.

The code I insert in the email is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
          <meta charset='utf-8' />
          <title>My Title</title>
       </head>
       <body bgcolor='#eaeaea' style='font-family:Verdana'>
          <div>
              <a href='http://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=MY_APP_ID&amp;href=URL_IMAGE&amp;redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/FAN_PAGE&amp;display=page'><div>Please share this image with your friends on Facebook:</div><BR><div><IMG SRC='URL_IMAGE'></a>
          </div>
       </body>
    </html>
```

I get the error that I can't redirect to that URL.

I have configured in the APP the url of the website where is stored the image, but I am not able to redirect to the fan page on facebook.

Answer (score 1):

I assume it is this error:

> Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

It seems that you can´t redirect directly to a facebook.com URL, you have to redirect to your own external website instead - and you have to add that URL/domain in your App settings. You could just implement a simple redirection from your external website to the fan page, as a workaround.

Comment: Hi thanks! Yes that's correct, but why I can't redirect to my fanpage?

Comment: because that´s how facebook implemented it ;)

Comment: not really, the redirection is basically there to get back to the real page after redirecting to the share dialog. it should not redirect to a completely different url.

Comment: either way, that´s just how it is.

Comment: In this case I "come" from the email

Comment: yeah, that would be a bit tricky - but you can just redirect to your own domain and implement a simple redirection to the facebook page ;)

Comment: That's exactly the first idea that came to my mind :) Thanks